# Missing Bib(la)tex directory in Texmaker

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, biber

I am having a nightmare with compiling citations using Texmaker. As part of this I was changing directories and somehow ended up with no directory. I have attempted uninstalling Texmaker and the MacTex as well as removing the program preferences but this hasn't worked. I know you can browse to the Bibtex file but I have no idea where it could be. Can anyone help me get back to some semblance of usage?

[image: Missing directory in texmaker]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be enough to enter `"bibtex" %.aux` or `"biber" %` in the empty field (assuming it is in your path)

Comment: Mandatory link to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: Yes, whilst that link was useful, you'll also see it contains the full path. That it could be done without the full path is what I didn't know and what these replies have helped me with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment variables are set to include the location of `bibtex` and/or `biber` you don't need to worry about the full path, just fill

```
"bibtex" %.aux
```

or

```
"biber" %
```

into the empty field.